# Symfony 4 .env variables in controller

Tags: environment-variables, symfony4

In Symfony 4, i try to pass parameter from my .env
to a controller:

- in `.env`:

```env
###> First user creation variables ###
FIRST_USER_LOGIN=admintest
FIRST_USER_PASSWORD=azertyui
###< First user creation variables ###
```

- in `services.yaml`:

```yaml
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    first.user:
        login: '%env(FIRST_USER_LOGIN)%'
        password: '%env(FIRST_USER_PASSWORD)%'
```

- in my controller:

```php
$utilisateur->setUsername($this->getParameter('first.user.login'))
    ->setPassword(
        $encoder->encodePassword(
            $utilisateur,
            $this->getParameter('first.user.password')
        )
    )
    ->setRoles(['ROLE_ADMIN']);
```

- I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I've got this error message:
  `The parameter "first.user.login" must be defined.`

Comment: Hello

I am trying to do the same in a class which in not extending Abstract controller. Do you know how I can do it ? 

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Solved: just changed the `services.yaml`:

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    first.user.login: '%env(FIRST_USER_LOGIN)%'
    first.user.password: '%env(FIRST_USER_PASSWORD)%'
```